# Changing the type of an array item in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an array on strings which I would like to map over and convert each item to numbers. I must be missing something because this works with vanilla js.

Even doing `digits[1] = Number(digits[1])` gives an error so I'm wondering how I can change the type of an array item.

```
const number = 12345;
let digits = number.toString().split(''); // ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
digits = digits.map(x => Number(x)); // Should be [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Instead I get

```
  Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the type of the variable. Instead you have to write it in one single expression like this:

```
const number = 12345;
const digits = number.toString().split('').map(x => Number(x));
```

Otherwise you first assign the type `string[]` to the variable and then try to assign `number[]` to the same variable.